# Maven: can not recognize package from dependency

Tags: maven

I created two maven projects, project A and B, I created a class called Teacher. 
I deployed project A to Nexus and wanted to use class Teacher in project B.

> Project A, class Teacher

[image]

> project A on Nexus

[image]

> project B added dependency A

[image]

> Use class Teacher in project B

[image]

After expand dependency, the Teacher class is exist
[image]
===========================================================
My question is that dependency A is added to Project B successfully, 
however, I can not use class Teacher in Project B.  IDE tell me "can not resolve symbol mvndddmo".

I could not understand what caused the problem.

Comment: Please expand dependency tree (only your com.mvndddmo...) to watch package and classes inside

Comment: @SergioGragera  I have added  a picture to show the dependency, please see the last pic

Comment: Your classes are on BOOT-INF, show the pom.xml from your A project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @SergioGragera is hinting at, your `com.mvndddemo:demothree` dependency is packaged in the wrong way. `Teacher.class` should be stored in the jar file directly under `com/mvndddemo/demothree` not under `BOOT-INF/classes`.

It seems that your dependency has been repackaged using the `spring-boot` plugin, which is great for Spring Boot applications but not so great if you need to depend on its classes.

You should break out the `Teacher` class (and perhaps others as well) into a separate Maven module or project that doesn't repackage the resulting jar file and depend on that.

Comment: Thank you for point out the solution. I solved the problem by revising the pom like this 
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <executable>true</executable>
    </configuration>
</plugin>